# Add uuid to database table

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to create uuid for an id of clients table, it works fine with normal id, but I need to use uuid. I am facing this errors and can't solve this issue.

Error message
`pq: null value in column "uid" of relation "clients" violates not-null constraint`

tried importing `"github.com/satori/go.uuid"`

with this

```golang
type Client struct {
    UID  string `gorm:"type:uuid;primary_key;default:uuid_generate_v4()"`
    Name string
}

func (u *Client) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    u.UID = uuid.New()
    return
}
```

"New not declared by package uuid"

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-From-SQL-Expression-Context-Valuer

Comment: I did as in docs, still doesn't work and doesn't state what exactly needs to be improted.

Comment: You can import satori/uuid like this `import (uuid "github.com/satori/go.uuid")`and inside BeforeCreate assign the UID like this `u.UID = uuid.NewV4().String()`. Be sure to `go get` satori's package or run `go mod tidy`